# <signed number> expected, got 'UserID' Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite

While working on android studio, I was creating a Many to Many relation and foreign key in it but it gives an error after COL_1. Please help me to remove this error.
Thank you
Error:

```
<signed number> expected, got 'UserID':100
```

Code:
Error is at the braces after COL_1.

```
package com.example.app;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import com.example.app.data.AlarmReminderContract;
import com.example.app.data.model.Alarm;
import com.example.app.data.model.BloodSugarClass;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "carbcounter.db";
    private static final String USER_TABLE = "user";
    private static final String BLOOD_SUGAR_TABLE="Blood_Sugar";
    private static final String REMINDER_TABLE="reminder";
    public static final String FOOD_TABLE="Food_Table";
    public static final String PATIENT_TABLE="Patient";
    public static final String PATIENT_SUGAR_TABLE="User_Sugar";
    public static final String STATISTICS_TABLE="Statistics";
    public static final String INSULIN_TABLE="Insulin";
    //user table
    private static final String COL_1 = "UserID";
    private static final String COL_2 = "First_Name";
    private static final String COL_3 = "Last_Name";
    private static final String COL_4 = "Email";
    private static final String COL_5 = "Username";
    private static final String COL_6 = "Password";
    private static final String COL_7 = "Age";
    private static final String COL_8 = "Weight";
    private static final String COL_9 = "Height";
    private static final String COL_10 = "Gender";
    //sugar table
    private static final String BloodSugarId = "BloodGlucoseId";
    private static final String sugar_level = "Sugar_Level";
    private static final String unit = "Unit";
    private static final String measuredTime = "Measured_Time";
    private static final String date = "Date";
    private static final String time = "Time";
    private static final String note = "Notes";
    //food table
    public static final String FoodId = "FoodId";
    public static final String foodName = "Food";
    public static final String Unit = "Unit";
    public static final String FoodMeasure = "Measure";
    public static final String grams = "Grams";
    public static final String calories = "Calories";
    public static final String protein = "Protein";
    public static final String fats = "Fat";
    public static final String carbs = "Carbs";
    public static final String category = "Category";
    //Patient table
    public static final String PatientId = "PatientId";
    public static final String PatientWeight = "Weight";
    public static final String DiabetesType = "DiabetesType";
    public static final String InsulinDosePerDay = "InsulinDosePerDay";
    public static final String PatientInsulinUnit = "InsulinUnit";
    //Patient sugar table
    public static final String UserBloodSugarID="UserBloodSugarID";
    public static final String UFK1 = "UserID";
    public static final String UFK2 = "BloodGlucoseId";
    //Statistics table
    public static final String StatisticsID="StatisticsID";
    public static final String StatisticsDate="StatisticsDate";
    public static final String StatisticsToDate="ToDate";
    public static final String StatisticsFromDate="FromDate";
    //Insulin table
    public static final String InsulinDoseID="InsulinDoseID";
    public static final String InsulinName="InsulinName";
    public static final String InsulinType="InsulinType";
    public static final String InsulinDoseTiming="InsulinDoseTiming";
    public static final String InsulinDoseUnit="InsulinUnit";


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        // Create a String that contains the SQL statement to create the reminder table
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + USER_TABLE + " ( "+ COL_1 +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+COL_2+" Text, "+COL_3+" Text,"+COL_4+" Text,"+COL_5+" Text,"+COL_6+" Password,"+COL_7+" Integer, "+COL_8+" Integer, "+COL_9+" Integer,"+COL_10+" Text)");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + BLOOD_SUGAR_TABLE + " ( "+ BloodSugarId +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+sugar_level+" Integer, "+unit+" Text,"+measuredTime+" Text,"+date+" Date,"+time+" Time, "+note+" Text)");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + FOOD_TABLE + " ( "+ FoodId +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+foodName+" Text, "+FoodMeasure+" INTEGER,"+Unit+" TEXT," +grams+" INTEGER,"+calories+" INTEGER,"+protein+" INTEGER, "+fats+" INTEGER, "+carbs+" INTEGER,"+category+" Text)");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + PATIENT_TABLE + " ( "+ PatientId +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+PatientWeight+" FLOAT, "+DiabetesType+" String,"+InsulinDosePerDay+" Integer,"+PatientInsulinUnit+" Integer)");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + PATIENT_SUGAR_TABLE +"("+UserBloodSugarID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + UFK1+ " FOREIGN KEY " +USER_TABLE +"("+COL_1+")" + UFK2+ " FOREIGN KEY " +BLOOD_SUGAR_TABLE+"("+BloodSugarId+")"); //Line 100
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + STATISTICS_TABLE +"("+ StatisticsID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + StatisticsDate+"Date,"+StatisticsFromDate+"Date,"+ StatisticsToDate+"Date)");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + INSULIN_TABLE +"("+ InsulinDoseID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + InsulinName+"Text,"+InsulinType+"Text,"+InsulinDoseTiming+"Time,"+InsulinDoseUnit+"Integer)");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " +REMINDER_TABLE + " ("
                + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_DATE + " TEXT , "
                + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TIME + " TEXT , "
                + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT_NO + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_REPEAT_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_ACTIVE + " TEXT NOT NULL " + " );");
    }
```

I am unable to find any solution. I don't know if the syntax of foreign key is right or wrong. If it is wrong than please tell me the right one.

Comment: Try using `sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + PATIENT_SUGAR_TABLE +"("+UserBloodSugarID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + UFK1+" FOREIGN KEY "+USER_TABLE +"("+COL_1+")" + UFK2+" FOREIGN KEY "+BLOOD_SUGAR_TABLE+"("+BloodSugarId+")");` i.e. add spaces around keywords such as INTEGER and FOREIGN KEY. **Note** *this was before the questions was edited*

Comment: @MikeT After adding spaces error on Foreign Key is: )', <column constraint>, <type name> or comma expected, got 'FOREIGN'

Comment: Edit your question to include the entire class, so that all the variables are available.

Comment: I edited my question now you can check @MikeT

Comment: What is the full stack trace? Please edit your question to show it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is that you are trying to code a table level Foreign Key constraint at the column level.

That is, you can define the Foreign key constraint either as part of the column definition (does not cater for composite (multiple column) foreign keys) or later as part of the table definition.

If at the column level then the column name is inferred so you just need to define the table and column that is referenced and hence just

- `the_column_being_defined the_column_type_etc REFERENCES the_referenced_table(the_referenced_column)`.

If at the table level then you need to specify the column(s) that the foreign key is applied to along with the table and column(s) that are referenced. So

- `FOREIGN KEY (the_columns_to_be_applied_to) REFERENCES the_refrenced_table(the_referenced_columns)`

I believe is what you want:-

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + PATIENT_SUGAR_TABLE +"("+UserBloodSugarID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + UFK1+" INTEGER REFERENCES "+USER_TABLE +" ("+COL_1+")," + UFK2+" INTEGER  REFERENCES "+BLOOD_SUGAR_TABLE+"("+BloodSugarId+"))");
```

This results in (column names may differ) in (via App Inspection) :-

[image]

See https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html (expand the relevant sections)